# Github Pages: How to access github project page when root site is jekyll

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

My website is running on Jekyll being hosted at dashedstripes.github.io (which i have rooted to my own domain), I'd like to set up another repository to be a project page i.e dashedstripes.github.io/project-name

I've setup a separate project repo with a gh-pages branch which is saying it is live at dashedstripes.github.io/project-name

However, because the root site is being run on jekyll, I'm being given a 404 whenever trying to access that project.

Is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, you have no index page at the root and you get a `404`. If you try http://adamgray.so/what-should-i-eat/dist/, you hit your `index.html`.

You need to publish `dist` folder content at the root of your `gh-page` branch.

Comment: Thank You! I'm very new to gh-pages, I knew it must have been something simple!